# Size .NET Windows form so that control (picturebox) is desired size and maintain aspect ratio while resizing

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, user-interface, picturebox

I am trying to make a .Net WinForms window with a simple Toolstrip and a single picture box.

```
   Dim img As Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filename)))
   PictureBox1.Image = img
   PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
   ratio = img.Height / img.Width
```

The image displays fine, my problem is that I'm trying to get the Form to size correctly to display the image at its correct resolution with its correct aspect ratio. And because there is more to the form that just the picturebox I'm not sure how to the resize.

If I do

```
Me.Width = Me.Height * Ratio
```

then the ratio isn't accurate due to the space required for the window borders and Toolstrip. How do I set the Forms initial size to make the Picturebox size exactly equal to the image dimensions?

Found the answer is:

```
Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(img.Width, img.Height + ToolStrip1.Height)
```

To resize while maintaining the aspect ratio the code is:

```
Dim ratio as Double

Private Sub Form_Shown(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
  Dim img As Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(_filename)))
  PictureBox1.Image = img
  PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
  Image_ratio = img.Height / img.Width

  Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(img.Width, img.Height + ToolStrip1.Height)
  Me.Activate()

  AddHandler Me.Resize, AddressOf Form_SizeChanged
End Sub

Private Sub Form_SizeChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  'Resize while maintaining aspect ratio
   Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(PictureBox1.Height / Image_ratio, Me.ClientSize.Height)
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for `Form1.Width = Form1.With * ratio` and `Form1.Height = Form1.Height * ratio`

Comment: possible duplicate of [preserve form's aspect ratio upon resize in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391394/preserve-forms-aspect-ratio-upon-resize-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @HansPassant I'd clarified the question a bit more.

Comment: Well, clearly you don't want to use Width and Height.  Take the resized Height as a start point, subtract the fixed parts like the title bar, tool strip and bottom order.  Gives you a new height for the picture box.  Gives you a new width for the box by the aspect ratio, add the fixed parts, gives you a new desired ClientSize.Width, add the borders.  Repeat for Width.  Before you commit to this, do note the very lousy user interface.  The mouse cursor becomes disconnected from the window corner, very dis-orienting to the user.  So try it first to make sure you actually want to write this code.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware of the Forms Me.Clientsize, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer is:

```
Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(img.Width, img.Height + ToolStrip1.Height)
```

To resize while maintaining the aspect ratio the code is:

```
Dim ratio as Double

Private Sub Form_Shown(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
  Dim img As Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(_filename)))
  PictureBox1.Image = img
  PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
  Image_ratio = img.Height / img.Width

  Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(img.Width, img.Height + ToolStrip1.Height)
  Me.Activate()

  AddHandler Me.Resize, AddressOf Form_SizeChanged
End Sub

Private Sub Form_SizeChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  'Resize while maintaining aspect ratio
   Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(PictureBox1.Height / Image_ratio, Me.ClientSize.Height)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a Panel to your form and set its Dock property to Fill, so that it fills all the space in the form other than that occupied by the ToolStrip.  Add the PictureBox to the Panel, setting its Location to (0,0) and its SizeMode property to AutoSize.  When you set the Image of the PictureBox, the Size will change automatically to fit the Image.  You can then resize the form like so:

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_SizeChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.SizeChanged
    Me.Size = New Size(Me.Width + Me.PictureBox1.Width - Me.Panel1.Width,
                       Me.Height + Me.PictureBox1.Height - Me.Panel1.Height)
End Sub
```

Comment: @jmcihinney I tried implementing that but the sizing doesn't seem to work. Won't the Picturebox.width - panel1.width also equal 0?

Comment: No, they will not be equal.  The Panel will have its Size controlled by the form and the PictureBox will have its Size controlled by the Image.  Did you do as instructed and set the SizeMode to AutoSize?

Comment: Ah, it is SizeMode not AutoSizeMode.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Mind you, given that there is no AutoSizeMode property, I don't understand why you didn't either realise the mistake and correct it yourself or else ask about it.  It seems that you just ignored it and ignoring part of a solution is unlikely to solve the problem.

Comment: I thought it was the panel Autosize, and thank you for your help!