# Restrict resizable panel (ratio & min/max size)

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, aspect-ratio, resizable

I'm currently trying to add a resizable panel to my C# winforms project.

Currently i'm using this code to get what i want:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class ResizablePanel : Panel
{
    private const int grab = 16;

    public ResizablePanel()
    {
        this.ResizeRedraw = true;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        var rc = new Rectangle(this.ClientSize.Width - grab, this.ClientSize.Height - grab, grab, grab);
        ControlPaint.DrawSizeGrip(e.Graphics, this.BackColor, rc);
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        if (m.Msg == 0x84)
        {
            var pos = this.PointToClient(new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32() & 0xffff, m.LParam.ToInt32() >> 16));

            if (pos.X >= this.ClientSize.Width - grab && pos.Y >= this.ClientSize.Height - grab)
                m.Result = new IntPtr(17);
        }
    }
}
```

Its working fine but now i would like to limit a few things.

1. I dont want the panel to be smaller than 420x236.
   I tried to set the MinimumSize but its ignoring that when i try to resize.
2. I want to keep an aspect ratio of 16:9.

How would i get that with the code above? Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried SetBoundsCore()? It's a virtual method and you can use it in situations like yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the WM_SIZING message, adopted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3391721/815938).

```
if (m.Msg == 0x84)
{
    var pos = this.PointToClient(new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32() & 0xffff, m.LParam.ToInt32() >> 16));

    if (pos.X >= this.ClientSize.Width - grab && pos.Y >= this.ClientSize.Height - grab)
    m.Result = new IntPtr(17);
}
else if (m.Msg == 0x216 || m.Msg == 0x214)
{ 
    // WM_MOVING || WM_SIZING
    // Keep the aspect and minimum size
    RECT rc = (RECT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(RECT));
    int w = rc.Right - rc.Left;
    int h = rc.Bottom - rc.Top;
    w = w > 420 ? w : 420;
    rc.Bottom = rc.Top + (int)(w * 9.0 / 16);
    rc.Right = rc.Left + w;
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(rc, m.LParam, false);
    m.Result = (IntPtr)1;
    return;
}
```

The RECT struct is defined as

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT {
    public int Left;
    public int Top;
    public int Right;
    public int Bottom;
}
```

I also tried overriding `OnResize` event, which is much simpler, however, the panel is flickering when being resized.

```
protected override void OnResize(EventArgs eventargs)
{
    base.OnResize(eventargs);
    if (this.Width < 420)
        this.Size = new Size(420, 236);
    else
        this.Size = new Size(this.Width, (int)(this.Width * 9.0 / 16));
}
```

Both approaches are actually the same thing, handling message queue is more low level "Win32-like" and overriding OnResize is "Windows Forms' way".

Comment: So i tried the OnResize version and its working fine. I fixed the flickering by using DoubleBuffered and overriding CreateParams. Even if OnResize is working i still would like to test the first version of your idea but i dont understand how/where to use that. I'm new to all that stuff and still learning, could you maybe give me a small "tutorial" about where and how to use that?

Comment: Oh and i saw that i would also need to include a limit to max height/width based on the size of the form because if you stretch it too big you cant grab the corner to make it small agin. :D

Comment: Just copy the code into your WndProc method, I just add an else if after your if.

Comment: @kennyzy Damn, seems like i need a small break, ofc its that, thank you!^^ What about the RECT? Its not a rectangle, what is it?

Comment: @Backslash yes, it is the equivalent for Rectangle in Win32

Comment: @kennyzy Just asking because it doesnt know how to use RECT and if i change that to Rectangle its throwing errors for rc.Bottom and rc.Right because they are protected.

Comment: Oh sorry! I did not copy the definition for the RECT struct. Please follow the link in my answer.

Comment: @kennyzy And again i'm sorry. Sitting here for hours and i definitely should take a break. I've read the link you posted but i completly ignored that part. Its working fine now! Now all i need to manage, is to limit the max height/width so the corner cant move out of the form before i can finally take a break. :D